# Integrating authorize.net in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

Im using contact form 7 (wordpress plugin) for contact form, now i need to integrate authprize.net to contact form 7, so that when user click on submit button after fill form, user should able to pay with authorize.net(only after submitting form). Does any one knows how to do it....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using woocommerce connected to an authorize.net account, you can use gravity forms with the woocommerce add on. This gives you the ability to use a form to create a custom priced product that is added to the cart.

Comment: The OP is using Contact 7 not Gravity Forms

Comment: Yes. Currently there are no plugins available to connect Authorize.net to Contact Forms 7. (I've searched far and wide) Either you must write your own plugin, or switch to a different form plugin such as Gravity Forms that does have Authorize.net compatibility